# WordPress theme de-activated

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a WordPress multisite and I create some themes for the sites will be hosted on that installation.

Suddenly, while I worked on the theme, and I refresh my code to see my changes, the WordPress de-activated my theme, and replace it by "Twenty Fourteen", and after that, I cannot find my theme in my Themes list.

The code I applied was not something special, just some HTML and some php echo.

Can somebody provide me with a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not given a lot to go on so I'll give some very generic advice.

WordPress no longer sees your them as a valid theme.

Check this [Theme Development Guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and pay special attention to the header that has to go in style.css. Make sure it is exactly as required.

HTH,

=C=